# What is the difference between node.js event loop and Kestrel (.net) worker process behavior?

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, iis

in node.js we have one event loop in single thread mode that responds to requests concurrently.

in .net development and in Kestrel there is one worker process that do the same but what is the differences?

Comment: I suppose *too many to list* depending on how in-depth you want the analysis.

Comment: @VLAZ i just want to know how they two respond so never one request block the whole process, in other word how they proceed each request?

Comment: They cannot compare to each other. You also misunderstood the relationship between IIS and Kestrel, https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1